# Can't log in extending FOS in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I have 3 classes (Auditor, Client and Manager) extending `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User` and several input forms to create every type.

For example, for Auditor class (the other are in the same way):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="auditor")
 */
class Auditor extends BaseUser implements NotificationInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;
```

When I create a new Auditor it works ok, it creates on the auditor table and everything is ok. But when I try to log in it doesn't work. Also, if I see the FOS users by `php app/console app:list-users` command, the new Auditor user does not appear.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't want to use another external bundle, I tried to solve in another way and I came up with this solution that finally works at all.

I extended FOS User entity in this way:

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
     * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
     * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
     * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"user" = "User","subscriber" = "Subscriber", "client" = "Client", "company" = "Company"})
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
     *
     */
    class User extends BaseUser
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;
```

And then in every subclass (Subscriber, Client and Company) I extended this subclass too (3 level hierarchy counting the FOS User). I paste below one of them (the same for the others):

```
use AppBundle\Entity\User as MyUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ClientRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="client")
 */
class Client extends MyUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
```

Hope this would help anyone...

Comment: Good approach. How can we have different access controls for different users?

Answer (score 1):

Although you have extended the classes from `BaseUser` class, you can't use multiple classes for login in `FOSUserBundle`. Check your `app/config/config.yml` file.

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
```

Here you have defined only one class as a fos_user.

Use [PUGXMultiUserBundle](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle) for your requirment.

> The PUGXMultiUserBundle extends FOSUserBundle adding the feature to handle users of different types.